# Matlab: Converting Timestamps to Readable Format given the Reference Date-Time

Tags: matlab, datetime, datetime-format, timestamp

I have a text file that contains timestamps out of a camera that captures 50 frames per second .. The data are as follows:

```
1 20931160389   
2 20931180407
3 20931200603   
4 20931220273   
5 20931240360
.
.
50 20932139319
```

... and so on.

It gives also the starting time of capturing like

```
Date: **02.03.2012 17:57:01**
```

The timestamps are in **microseconds** not in milliseconds, and MATLAB can support only till milliseconds but its OK for me.

Now I need to know the human format of these timestamps for each row..like

```
1   20931160389     02.03.2012 17:57:01.045  % just an example
2   20931180407     02.03.2012 17:57:01.066
3   20931200603     02.03.2012 17:57:01.083
4   20931220273     02.03.2012 17:57:01.105
5   20931240360     02.03.2012 17:57:01.124
```

and so on

I tried this:

```
%Refernce Data
clc; format longg
refTime = [2012,03,02,17,57,01];
refNum = datenum(refTime);
refStr = datestr(refNum,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF');

% Processing data
dn = 24*60*60*1000*1000; % Microseconds! I have changed this equation to many options but nothing was helpful
for i = 1 : size(Data,1)
  gzTm = double(Data{i,2}); %timestamps are uint64
  gzTm2 = gzTm / dn;
  gzTm2 = refNum + gzTm2;
  gzNum = datenum(gzTm2);
  gzStr = datestr(gzNum,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.FFF'); % I can't use 'SS.FFFFFF'
  fprintf('i = %d\t Timestamp = %f\t TimeStr = %s\n', i, gzTm, gzStr); 
end;
```

But I got always strange outputs like

```
i = 1    Timestamp = 20931160389.000000  TimeStr = **2012-03-08 13:29:28.849**
i = 2    Timestamp = 20931180407.000000  TimeStr = **2012-03-08 13:29:29.330**
i = 3    Timestamp = 20931200603.000000  TimeStr = **2012-03-08 13:29:29.815**
```

The output time is about some hours late/earlier than the Referenced Time. The day is different.

The time gap between each entry in the array should be nearly 20 seconds..since I have 50 frames per second(1000 millisecond / 50 = 20) ..and the year,month, day,hour,minute and seconds should also indicate the initial time given as reference time because it is about some seconds earlier.

I expect something like:

```
% just an example
1 20931160389 02.03.2012 **17:57:01.045** 
2 20931180407 02.03.2012 **17:57:01.066**
```

Could one help me please..! Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you can work out the number of microseconds between a record and the first record:

```
usecs = double(Data{i,2}) - double(Data{1,2});
```

convert that into seconds:

```
secsDiff = usecs / 1e6;
```

then add that to the initial datetime you'd calculated:

```
matDateTime = refNum + secsDiff / (24*60*60);
```

Comment: but he won't be able to find out the time difference between the reference time and the first entry.

Comment: @Alex: Thank you so much! It is solved. But could you just tell me where is my mistake? I can't figure out where is the point in solving such problems.

Comment: @memyself: To overcome this, I just add the refernce datetime as a first record to the array. Thanks everybody!

Comment: Btw, could someone tell me how to accept an answer to close the question? This is first time I'm here :-)

Comment: @Alex & memyself: Could you or anyone else help me solving my other question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10107804/matlab-tempo-alignment-according-to-timestamps). Thanks to all!