# Matlab: Tempo-Alignment according to Timestamps

Tags: matlab, alignment, video-capture, timestamp

May be it is so simple but I'm new to Matlab and not good in Timestamps issues in general. Sorry!

I have two different cameras each contains timestamps of frames. I read them to two arrays TimestampsCam1 and TimestampsCam2:

TimestampsCam1 contains 1500 records and the timestamps are in **Microseconds** as follows:

```
1 20931160389
2 20931180407
3 20931200603
4 20931220273
5 20931240360 ...
```

and TimestampsCam2 contains 1000 records and the timestamps are in **Milliseconds** as follows:

```
1 28275280  
2 28315443  
3 28355607  
4 28395771  
5 28435935 ...
```

The first camera starts capturing first and ends a bit later than the second camera. So what I need to do is to know exactly where a frame from first camera is captured at the same time (or nearly the same time) by the other camera. In other words, I want to align the two arrays(cameras) in time according to the timestamps. I want to get at the end two arrays of same size where each record is tempo-aligned to the corresponding record in the other array.

Many thanks to all!

Sam

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: your cameras don't appear to be synchronized

Comment: Yes, they are not synchronized. Camera1 starts timestamping from the initialization but those values are saved when I click the start recording button. The other camera do the same but with some differences. Now, my question is how to interpolate two different timestamps data, whatever the data are? I want simply to decide which frame from the first camera is aligned with another frame from the other camera by interpolation or any other method suitable for the purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they are in the same unit of measurement, e.g. microseconds

Create an index which contains all values, except duplicates, suppose this one is 2400 records long

Create two NaN vectors of length 2400 by putting the value (for example the framenumber) at the place where the index matches the timestamp

Now you have two aligned vectors with NaNs to pad them where required.